# Django 1.6 adding rows o excel sheet

Tags: python, django

I have one **table in excel sheet with username and amount fields**. I want to add additional rows to this table when user and number is incremented(by program). I am developing a application **using django**, excel file will be in local machine.

I will use workbook_open to open the excel file. I can't continue further because of adding rows to table with fields user name and amount in run time . However,I can't use xlwt module to do so. Can anyone suggest me to do so in **django 1.6**?

Comment: Why can't use **xwlt** ? What about a simple function with xwlt (or any other library) and **AJAX** ? You send the parameters to add/remove via **AJAX** and you have a python function with xwlt to update the file

Comment: xlwt is use to write the data to excel file. I want to add rows(it is a table with border) to excel file by using django. Can you suggest any other way?

Comment: I can't understand why you need another way, What's exactly you want to add to the file ? What do you mean by `(it is a table with border)` ? Do you want to add data to the excel file and some styles ? Can't you parse the data you have in your html to add it to your excel ?

Comment: I can add the data from html to excel, but I need border style for every user and amount fields. This is not possible in xlwt. I tried using reportlab,but there I have to create the excel file. But,In my application, I have to use existing excel file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I figured out the solution for adding rows to the table(with border) in excel sheet. I was using win32com port to do the task. Here is my code:

```
    import win32com.client as win32   

    exc = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")

    exc.Workbooks.Open("E:\\Invoice.xls")



    exc.Visible = 1

    row = 1
    no=4
    i=1
    count=0
    for m in Eng_name:
        if(m!=""):
            count=count+1

    while True:
        exc.Range("B%d" % row).Select()
        data = exc.ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1
        exc.Range("A%d" % row).Select()
        condition = exc.ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1


        if condition == INSERT_THIS:
            if(i==count):
                 break
            exc.Rows("%d" %(row)).Select()
            exc.Selection.Insert(Shift=constants.xlDown)
            i=i+1
            print i


        else:

            row += 1
```